# Delete Signature from email with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am currently in the process of anonymizing emails with vba for a project.

Currently when an email is received I have created a rule which moves the email into a folder, thereafter I run a script using the getlast function, in that specific folder, where I display the newly received email and copy the content of the email and then i paste this into a new email and send to a particular email address. This effectively removes the identifying features of the email.

The final movement to the Rubik's Cube is to find the email signature and replace with blank, in other words delete the signature. I will have the email signatures to do this, however it would be great if someone someone could help with this...

Answer (score 4):

I found this solution.

```
'I also had to add Word in tools/references of VBA and then Call DeleteSig(msg) after displaying the item.
'http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=259417

Sub DeleteSig(msg As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objBkm As Word.Bookmark
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objDoc = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
    If Not objBkm Is Nothing Then
        objBkm.Select
        objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
    End If
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objBkm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Example of call:
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
oMail.HTMLBody = stext & vbCr & oMail.HTMLBody
Call DeleteSig(oMail)

Answer (score 2):

It's not very hard, but depend on some properties of the mail:

- Is the mail plain text? or html
- if HTML, do you have the signature in html format ? (with tags)

I presume you read your mail with a variable of type `Outlook.MailItem`

```
' Definition of your mail
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
dim signature as string
...
with OutMail
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, signature, "")
End with
```

If the signature you have is not the exact match, it'll be a little more tricky.
I suggest to create a function that detect the signature and return the HTMLBody without it

Comment: I'll check this out and revert. Thanks for your suggestion, you're a hero!

Comment: I checked this out and it works to delete text in the email, so I can just delete the text. I was, however, having problems with deleting multiple lines, it seems easy to delete one line but I would like to delete multiple lines. The body is in html so I am trying use <br> but it does not appear to work...

Comment: Here the text is html, no trick. The simplest way is to directly open the html of your mail and look what it looks like (maybe he use <br/> instead of <br>.. I don't remember if outlook respect the <br /> convention).
Take a look of your HTML, it's the simplest. If you don't succeed, copy a piece of your html "before and after the <br>"

Comment: if the length of the signature is something static (ish) you can roughly during the process to replace olMailItem.body = left( olMailItem.body, len(olMailItem.body) - SignatureLength )... hope this helps