# Remove automatically generated signature in copied body of previous mail, from body of mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I create new mail, fill body and send it.

A VBA macro automatically creates a second email with same body and resends. The second mail has two signatures, one in body in line and one on the end of email.

Problem is, how to remove the first automatic signature in the second email.

```
.HTMLBody = objMail.Body & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```

but everything is in one line:

```
TEXT TEXT TEXT. Name, Surname, Address, Phone, etc.
```

My goal is remove signature from HTML body and add signature to end of email.

```
TEXT TEXT TEXT
signature
Name
Surename
Address
etc
```

When signature is disabled via user, it works perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Signature from email with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745343/delete-signature-from-email-with-vba)

Comment: I try it, and didnt work, can remove signature, but cant delete from body